# ASP.NET RadioButtonList loosing class="selected" when selection changes

Tags: asp.net

I have a very simple RadioButtonList that I have created:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblDisplayAs" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" RepeatLayout="UnorderedList" CssClass="tab-nav">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="List View" Value="list"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Calendar View" Value="cal"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

When the page loads, it renders like this:

```
<ul id="pagecontent_rblDisplayAs" class="tab-nav">
    <li class="selected">
        <input id="pagecontent_rblDisplayAs_0" type="radio" checked="checked" value="list">
        <label for="pagecontent_rblDisplayAs_0">List View</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input id="pagecontent_rblDisplayAs_1" type="radio" value="cal">
        <label for="pagecontent_rblDisplayAs_0">Calendar View</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have added some css rules for the "selected" class. However, when the user clicks on the radio button, the "selected" class is removed, and not applied to the newly-selected option.

How do I make sure that the list item holding currently selected/checked radio button always has the "selected" class?

EDIT:

If I add this to the code behind:

```
Protected Sub rblDisplayAs_SelectedIndexChanged(sender as Object, e AS EventArgs) Handles rblDisplayAs.SelectedIndexChanged
    rblDisplayAs.SelectedItem.Attributes.Add("class", "selected")
End Sub
```

Then after I change the selection it renders as:

```
<ul id="pagecontent_rblDisplayAs" class="tab-nav">
    <li>
        <input id="pagecontent_rblDisplayAs_0" type="radio" checked="checked" value="list">
        <label for="pagecontent_rblDisplayAs_0">List View</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="selected">
            <input id="pagecontent_rblDisplayAs_1" type="radio" value="cal">
            <label for="pagecontent_rblDisplayAs_0">Calendar View</label>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

EDIT:

Here's the css. There are other places on the site which are not generated by asp.net controls that also use these styles.

```
ul.tab-nav {
    overflow: hidden; 
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px; 
    position: relative;
    height: 35px;
}
ul.tab-nav li {
    list-style: none; 
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px; 
    display: inline; 
    position: relative; 
    top: 5px; 
    line-height: 1.6;
    background: none;
}
ul.tab-nav li.selected {
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 10;
}
ul.tab-nav li input {
    display:none;
}
ul.tab-nav li a, ul.tab-nav li label
    font-size: 116.67%;
    font-size: 1.1667rem;
    color: #a6a6a6;
    font-family: 'FrutigerRoman', Arial;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 2px 2px 0px 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 26px;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
    background: #e9e9e9;
}
ul.tab-nav li.selected a, ul.tab-nav li.selected label {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; 
    padding: 2px 2px 5px 2px; 
    bottom: 0px; 
    color: #00619d;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your css for the "selected" class?

Comment: I've added the css to the initial question.

Comment: I wonder if I just have to do something with jQuery and OnClientClick.... Or, well, radio buttons don't have OnClientClick but something similar...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for adding the css for the `ul` to your question.

There was a slight change required to the last css class in your code to get the selected style working correctly. Here is the full aspx, code and css which works for me in a test web app.

**ASPX**

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblDisplayAs" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" RepeatLayout="UnorderedList" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblDisplayAs_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="tab-nav">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="List View" Value="list"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Calendar View" Value="cal"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack) return;
    foreach (var li in rblDisplayAs.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(li => li.Selected))
        li.Attributes.Add("class", "selected");
}

protected void rblDisplayAs_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rblDisplayAs.SelectedItem.Attributes.Add("class", "selected");
}
```

**CSS**

```
ul.tab-nav {
    overflow: hidden; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    position: relative;
    height: 35px;
}

ul.tab-nav li {
    list-style: none; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    display: inline; 
    position: relative; 
    top: 5px; 
    line-height: 1.6;
    background: none;
}

ul.tab-nav li.selected {
    z-index: 10;
}

ul.tab-nav li input {
    display:none;
}

ul.tab-nav li a, ul.tab-nav li label {
    font-size: 116.67%;
    font-size: 1.1667rem;
    color: #a6a6a6;
    font-family: 'FrutigerRoman', Arial;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 0;
    padding: 2px 2px 0 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 26px;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
    background: #e9e9e9;
}

ul.tab-nav .selected label {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; 
    padding: 2px 2px 5px 2px; 
    bottom: 0;
    top: -5px;
    color: #00619d;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: It's not just the colour of the tab I need to have working, though; the li itself has a different style when it's selected (top:0 vs top:5px).

Comment: I've modified the css in my answer above. Does this achieve what you need?

Comment: That looks like it should work. I actually implemented a javascript solution to apply the class to the correct li when the radio selection changed... I'll try to remember to post it as an alternate solution when I'm back at work.